# Check Constraints and Case Statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need help with this check constraint, I get the following error message: "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near '='."

Or maybe the question I should ask is if this is possible using a check constraint

What I am trying to achieve is: If InformationRestricted is True, InformationNotRestricted cannot be true and InformationRestrictedFromLevel1, InformationRestrictedFromLevel2, InformationRestrictedFromLevel3, InformationRestrictedFromLevel4, InformationRestrictedFromLevel5 cannot be true

I am not trying to assign values to the columns, just trying to ensure the values of the columns = 0 (i.e. false) if InformationRestricted is True

Here is the script:

```
    CREATE TABLE EmployeeData
    (FirstName varchar(50),
    Last Name varchar(50),
    Age int,
    Address varchar(100),
    InformationRestricted bit,
    InformationNotRestricted bit,
    InformationRestrictedFromLevel1 bit,
    InformationRestrictedFromLevel2 bit
    InformationRestrictedFromLevel3 bit
    InformationRestrictedFromLevel4 bit
    InformationRestrictedFromLevel5 bit);

    ALTER TABLE EmployeeData ADD CONSTRAINT ck_EmployeeData
    CHECK (CASE WHEN InformationRestricted = 1 THEN InformationNotRestricted = 0         --InformationRestricted is true, InformationNotRestricted is false
    AND( InformationRestrictedFromLevel1 = 0 --is false
    OR InformationRestrictedFromLevel2 = 0 --is false
    OR InformationRestrictedFromLevel3 = 0 --is false
    OR InformationRestrictedFromLevel4 = 0 --is false
    OR InformationRestrictedFromLevel5 = 0)); --is false
```

Answer (score 6):

A `CASE` *expression* is something that returns a value of a particular data type (the type to be determined by the various datatypes of each `THEN` clause).

SQL Server doesn't *have* a boolean data type, so you can't return the result of a comparison operation.

Try adding additional comparisons into `WHEN` clauses, and having the `THEN`s return either 1 or 0, if you want to allow or disallow the outcome (respectively). Then compare the overall result to 1.

I can't parse out the sense of your condition entirely, but something like:

```
CHECK(CASE WHEN InformationRestricted = 1 THEN
     CASE WHEN InformationNotRestricted = 0 AND
        (InformationRestrictedFromLevel1 = 0 --is false
        OR InformationRestrictedFromLevel2 = 0 --is false
        OR InformationRestrictedFromLevel3 = 0 --is false
        OR InformationRestrictedFromLevel4 = 0 --is false
        OR InformationRestrictedFromLevel5 = 0)
         THEN 1
         ELSE 0
     END
--Other conditions?
END = 1)
```

---

My confusion is I'd have though you'd want to check that one and only one of the `InformationRestrictedFromXXX` columns would be one. In fact, from the general description, (without knowing more about your problem domain), I'd have probably just created a column `InformationRestrictionLevel`, of type `int`, with `0` meaning unrestricted, and higher values indicating the level it's restricted from.

Comment: The inner CASE could probably be merged with the outer one. +1 anyway, this is how CASE works.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you're not closing the `case` with `end`.  The basic format of a check constraint using case is:

```
check(case when <condition> then 1 else 0 end = 1)
```

If you nest multiple cases, be sure to match the number of cases with the number of ends:

```
check
(
    1 =
    case 
    when <condition> then 
        case 
        when <condition> then 1 
        else 0 
        end 
    else 0 
    end
)
```

Formatting all elements of the same `case` with the same indentation can be a big help.